# Boolean field query with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Postgres model:

```
class Song(db.Model):
    id3_parsed = db.Column(db.Boolean, server_default=u'false')
```

Running the following query gives the correct count:

```
select count(*) from song where id3_parsed is false;
```

But how do I do it with flask-sqlalchemy? This doesn't work:

```
songs = Song.query.filter(Song.id3_parsed == False).all()
```

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.is_

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
songs = Song.query.filter(Song.id3_parsed.is_(False)).all()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query seems to be right, looks like this is flake8 issue.

And that you can ignore by adding `# noqa` in the line you wrote.